# Automatic Refresh With Webpack in Electron

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

I have an Electron/Webpack project to which I am trying to add automatic refresh on file change. Per the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html), I've taken the following steps:

1. I added `webpack-dev-server` to my project.
2. I added the following to my `webpack.config.js`:

   ```
   devServer: {
       inline: true
   }
   ```
3. And I run webpack with the command `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors`

When I make changes to my entry file, they are not reflected in the emitted code at `http://localhost:8080/build/index.js` (where I have set my output to go). What am I missing?

For completeness, here is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: './build/index.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is running a local web server really the way to go? The electron main process functionality is lacking, so for most apps that won't work. I was hoping there is more like a build-in reload capability in Electron.

Answer (score 1):

maybe my test-boilerplate will give you some inspirations, the "web" environment offers HMR development:

https://github.com/wende60/Electron-Webpack2-React-Sass

cheers, joachim

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It helped me understand how to structure my `webpack` config and properly set the targets: `web` vs. `electron`.